# What does "const name{something}" mean?

Tags: c++, syntax

I have the following construction in the code:

```
const a{b(x,y)}
```

`b` looks like a function, but what does `a{}` mean?

**EDITED**

Yes it compiles. Is it "c++ initializer list"?

**EDITED 2**

To be more accurate this is the line from the code:

```
const abb::cfd lpm{dos::pre(ref<glm::pro>(inp, qvo)};
```

**Edited 3**

The first example line was incorrect. `a` does have a type. So, it is "c++ initializer list" (whatever it means). Now I know what I should google and read. Thank you.

Comment: What context is this in? It looks like it is missing something.

Comment: That was going to be a good question, if you just posted the real code at the very beginning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `a` does not have a type, this looks like invalid code.

If `a` had a type, then `{b(x,y)}` would be a [C++ 11 initializer list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Initializer_lists):

```
int x, y;
int b(int,int) { return 0; }
const int a{b(x,y)};
```

**edit:** With regards to your actual code, yes, `{dos::pre(ref<glm::pro>(inp), qvo)}` is an initializer list.